# Why can my file not be read in java?

Tags: java, file, text-files, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to simply read a text document in java. The file is being found by my program; I can see that it is able to determine the correct absolute path through various tests, but the problem seems to be that my program doesn't have permission to view the file?

```
File names = new File("names.txt");
if(names.setReadable(true, false (edit: true)))
    System.out.println("Can now be read");
if(names.canRead())
    System.out.println("Can be read");

FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(names);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
```

The boolean expression in each if statement evaluates to false, and I cannot understand why, or how to change it. I run into a FileNotFoundException where I attempt to create a new FileInputStream, which I read is due the the file being unreadable.

EDIT: Now I have changed the second paramater for the setReadable method call to true, and that part works (it prints "Can now be read"); so it seems that the file is being found and set as readable but still the second if statement fails and the program cannot access the text document.

Comment: If your exception is FileNotFoundException, you wrongly point the file position.  File file = new File("C:\\filePath\\yourfile.txt");

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
if(names.setReadable(true, true))
```

The second argument should be `true` so that the owner can access the file.

If you set it to false the program won't be able to read the file.

For more information read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_setreadable_owner.htm).